# Matching problem with multiples assigment

Tags: algorithm, math

## Introduction

I have a bipartite graph with workers(W) and Tasks(T).
Te goal is assign all task to the workers to minimize the maximum time spend. IE finish the last tasks as soon as possible.

## Question

1. What modification to the Hungarian algorithm have to be done to accomplish this task.
2. If Hungarian algorithm is not useful what could be a good mathematical approach?

Mathematically i don't know how to work with **multiple** task assignments for workers.
I will implement it in python once i understand the math theory.

## Problem

### Conditions:

- A task can only be assigned to one worker
- There isn't any restriction in the amount of task
- All task must be assigned
- A worker could have multiple task assigned
- There isn't any restriction in the amount of workers
- A worker could have no assignation.
- Workers are not free to start working at the same time

### Example

If i have 7 task `T={T₁, T₂, T₃, T₄, T₅, T₆, T₇}` and 3 workers `W={W₁, W₂, W₃}`, workers will be free to start working in `F={4, 7, 8}` (where `Fᵢ` is the time `Wᵢ` needs to be free to start working) and the cost matrix is:

[image]
A matching example could be (not necessary correct in this case, is just an example):

- W₁ = {T₁, T₂, T₃}
- W₂ = {T₄, T₅}
- W₃ = {T₆, T₇}

in this case the time expend for each worker is:

1. Time(W₁) = 4+5+4+3 = 16
2. Time(W₂) = 7+4+9 = 20
3. Time(W₃) = 8+1+7 = 16

### Explained as:

1. For W₁, we have to wait for:

   - 4 till he is free
   - after that he will finish T₁ in 5
   - T₂ in 4
   - T₃ in 3
   - **giving a total time of 16**.
2. For W₂, we have to wait for:

   - 7 till he is free
   - After that he will finish T₄ in 4
   - T₅ in 9
   - **Giving a total time of 20**.
3. For W₃, we have to wait for:

   - 8 till he is free
   - after that he will finish T₆ in 1
   - T₇ in 7
   - **Giving a total time of 16**.

## Goal

Minimize the maximum total time. Not the sum of totals.

If Total times {9, 6, 6} (sum 21) is a solution then {9, 9, 9} (sum 27) is a solution too and {10, 1, 1} (sum 12) is not because in the first and second case the last task is finished at time 9 and in the third case in time 10.

Comment: The Hungarian algorithm is an algorithm for the assignment problem, but this looks like parallel scheduling. Which is NP-complete.

Comment: Yeah it's NP hard. It's a generalization of equal subset sums, which you can see in the case where all the jobs have equal weight for each worker, and there are only two workers. The best you can do is divide the jobs between the workers to get the sums as close as possible to equal.  (It's not a classical scheduling problem afaics. They usually have order constraints on the jobs.)